# PHP foreach loop key value error

Tags: php, foreach, key, key-value

I want to loop array keys and values for my html form. 
**Array:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 50e54d84d681c00e603935e3
    [controller] => osmf
    [defaultServiceUrl] => http://media.netd.com.tr
    [serviceUrl] => http://37.48.66.143
    [path] => S1/HLS_VOD/5ea1_1536/index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94&app=com.dcom&max=1500
    [preview] => //s.dogannet.tv/q/i/76/1600x900/50e54e8cd681c00e603935e4
)
```

**And here is my PHP code:**

```
<?php
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { 
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></input>
    <?php
    }
```

**But output is:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="50e54d84d681c00e603935e3"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="" value="osmf"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="" value="http://media.netd.com.tr"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="" value="http://37.48.66.141"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="" value="S1/HLS_VOD/5ea1_1536/index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94&app=com.dcom&max=1500"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="" value="//s.dogannet.tv/q/i/76/1600x900/50e54e8cd681c00e603935e4"></input>
```

I can't see **name** s. On my html form names are empty.

Comment: you missed an `echo`: `name="<?php echo $key; ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo` the value of `$key`. By now you are just doing `<?php $key; ?>`, which does not perform anything. Hence, do:

```
<?php print $key; ?>"
```

All together, instead of

```
<?php
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { 
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></input>
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    <?php
    }
```

Use

```
<?php
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { 
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></input>
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: your answer below a PHP question? :)

Comment: We are everywhere, @hek2mgl :D (I used to enter here, then I moved to *NIX)

Comment: :) Note that with short_tags enabled you can also use `<?= $key ?>`. However `echo` is more portable ...